# Symfony 3.4 get error "2006 MySQL server has gone away"

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Sometimes when users access application ... there is exception thrown 
after that application works normally for a while and if there is no activity for a while i got that exception again.

`Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away" at /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php line 107 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: HY000): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away at /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:107, PDOException(code: HY000): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away at /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:105)"} []`

My PHP version is 5.6

Mysql version is 5.6

I google it for some answers and nothing worked with me.

**Debug results**
`SHOW STATUS WHERE`variable_name`= 'Threads_connected'`

`SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name LIKE "Threads_%" OR variable_name = "Connections"`

[image]

```
Mysql max number of connection = 100
session wait_timeout = 328800
global wait_timeout = 328800
```

Comment: What do you mean by pining connection every now ?

Comment: Is this some kind of a console script you are running your code in?

Comment: No it is not a console script ... just normal Symfony application running on server ... it is working fine on local environment

Comment: It might be based on the packet size being sent. Ran into this issue for a school project last year. As with yours, it worked with no issues locally. Hosted the app on Microsoft Azure with ClearDB and this issue happened to me. Connection gets closed if the packet is too big.  Possibly try upping the max size using steps in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/packet-too-large.html to increase the size .